# assigning another object's value to this c#

Tags: c#

I am having this class:

```
public class A
{
    public int Var1 { get; set; }
    public int Var2 { get; set; }
    public int Var3 { get; set; }


    public A()
    {

    }

    public void Load(A sender)
    {
        this.Var1 = sender.Var1;
        this.Var2 = sender.Var2;
        this.Var3 = sender.Var3;
    }
}
```

Since i have a lot of variables in my class, i do not want to assign each value every time inside my Load function, is there a way i say like `this = sender` since both are same type?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: There is not, and also you are likely writing a copy-constructor so you should declare it as such: `public A(A other)`.

Comment: Search for "clone object in c#".

Comment: I think that this is more of a [`copy constructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) problem rather than simple cloning.

Comment: I already closed too many posts as duplicates today... When answering "how to clone object" please make sure to meet, or preferably exceed quality of answers to roughly the same question here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: None of referring comments didn't work and are not same as this case, but answer from HimBromBeere markd question did work.